# how to make a simple event

Tags: javascript, html, events

```js
window.onload = term;

function term () {
var term = document.getElementById("list").value;
return term;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src = "review2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
Term: <input type = "text" id = "list">
<input type = "button" onclick= "list" value= "submit">
</body>

</html>
```

trying to make a simple javascript have a user input a term and it go onto the html page. but for some reason it wont. any reason why?

Comment: `onclick= "list"` doesn’t do anything. You need to call the function. Where is `list` defined? Anyway, you should be using `addEventListener` instead of event attributes.

Comment: Do you want to go current section on loaded page or go to other page !

Answer (score 0):

you can define events by using the `addEventListener` function (directly in JS) or the `on*` (like `onclick`) DHTML attributes on the respective element (as on your example). But, as in the comments of your question noticed, you need to define the JS function, which should be called / used, when the user clicks the button. "list" is - at least on your example - not defined, so it doesn't work at all.

Short Example with the `addEventListener` method:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var val = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if(val.trim() !== ""){
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = "Passed Value: " + val;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = "No passed value!";
  }
});
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" id="input" />
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</p>
<p id="output">
  
</p>
```

Short example with the DHTML Attribute `onclick`:

```js
function list(){
  var val = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  if(val.trim() !== ""){
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = "Passed Value: " + val;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = "No Value Passed!";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" id="input" />
  <button id="submit" onclick="list()">Submit</button>
</p>
<p id="output">
  
</p>
```

You can find more informations about events on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp).

Sincerely,
Sam